# Can anyone help me with some basic action script 3.0?

Tags: flash, animation

I am an art student who is looking to create a simple interactive document to display in my end of year show. I have had some experience with flash, but with time as an issue I don't have long enough to learn the basics needed for this project, so if anyone could suggest what I'd need for this to work that'd be fantastic.

The document would involve multiple movie clip symbols which are simple coloured dots moving around the scene in looped animations. All I want is for the viewer to be able to toggle the visibility of these independent symbols using the keys on a keyboard. For example;

Release Q = toggle visibility of dot 1 on/off

Release W = toggle visibility of dot 2 on/off

etc.

The result would be a simple document with a number of moving coloured dots that, using the keyboard, the viewer could toggle on or off to create different colour combinations.

I would have the document set up to `stop ();` on frame 1 and then have the motion of each dot keyed into its independent timeline on its own layer.

Any help would be massively appreciated as this would certainly look good in my show.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really simple AS3 that work for movieclip instance already on stage

```
//Circle movieClip Code
gotoAndStop(Math.ceil(Math.random() * this.totalFrames)) //choose a random frame (circle color)

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp) // Question use "Release"
function onKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent){
    if(event.keyCode == 81){// Q keyCode
        this.visible = !this.visible
    }
}
```

Comment: You are an absolute star my friend, I really appreciate that you took time to help me here. Thank you so much!